# Quick Regex Help - JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to use regular expressions to find part of a string from a string,

So say for example my string is:

```
string = "Hello my name is carl how are you doing?";
```

And I want to match the name "carl", how would I go about doing that?

This is what I have got,

```
.*?(?=\show)
```

My problem is NOT matching the text "Hello my name is "

Cheers

Carl

Comment: It's unclear what you want: do you just want to know whether a given substring exists within a string? (i.e. "Is {needle} in {haystack}?")

Comment: Accept an answer and close this question if one worked.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to `\w+(?=\show)`:

```
> var string = "Hello my name is carl how are you doing?";
> /\w+(?=\show)/.exec(string)
["carl"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var m = myStr.match(/(\w+) how are you doing\?/)
if (m) { name = m[1]; }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but the string "carl" for example will change, so I need to use a whiled card or something.

Comment: ok misunderstood. see update - it only works for single names, for multiple names, we'd have to use the prefix: `var m = myStr.match(/is (.+) how are you doing\?/)`

Comment: That seems to match the string "carl how are you doing?" I m trying to pull just the word "carl",

Comment: it returns an array. the group in the parentheses is retrieved by `name = m[1]`.

Comment: Ahh rite I see. Is there not a way to just, NOT match some text or characters on the left side and not match some characters or text on the right side? thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: you can lookahead as as in @alecxe's answer `/\w+(?=\show)/`, but my comment above is the only way you can match a string based on what comes before it.